# How to handle mass mail sending with queue timeout

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have table with 100K+ emails where I want to daily send some email:

I added schedule in app\Console\Kernel.php:

```
$schedule->job(new SendDailyEmails)->dailyAt('09:00');
```

Inside Job I have:

```
$users = User::all();
foreach($users as $user){
    Maill:to($user->email)->send(new DailyMail($user));
    $status = 'sent';
    if( in_array($user->email, Mail::failures()) ){
        $status = 'failed';
        Log::error($user->email . ' was not sent.');
    }else{
        Log::info($user->email . ' was sent.');
    }
    SentMail::create([
        'email' => $user->email,
        'status' => $status
    ]);

}
```

This works fine, but after some time this stops probably because job timeout. In failed_jobs table I get `MaxAttemptsExceededException` with message that Job attempted too many times or run too long. Since I set queue tries max to 3 within supervisor it should and do go 3 times only. And by testing things it did not try to attempt again because I got one mail instead of 3.

So it comes to timeout and I am not sure what is default value but does it matter since I will not know how much time it would take to send all emails?

Should I divide mails into groups of 50 and call separate job instances for each group?

Anyone have a good working answer for this?

Comment: Does your job implement `ShouldQueue`?

Comment: yes it does.....

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail#queueing-mail) you will find out that every single mail can be queued.

So, you should change your job from

```php
Mail:to($user->email)->send(new DailyMail($user));
```

to

```php
Mail:to($user->email)->queue(new DailyMail($user));
```

In this way you will push into the queue every single mail your job generates. I suggest you to create a specific queue and use system like [laravel horizon](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/horizon) for a better monitoring.

Also remember to chunk and delay the sending because your application can run a timeout error, but also providers like [mailgun](https://www.mailgun.com/) may block your sending if they see an unusual activity.

Comment: Could you explain to me the difference between your and Caddy's answer?

Comment: if you call `send()` on a mail that implements `ShouldQueue` it should already push it into the queue, no matter how you try to send it. Then you must call `php artisan queue:work ...` to start sending them.

Comment: @Learner the final result is the same but he's dispatching a job and and when the queue executes the job, it will send the email during the execution. So if the mail throws an error, the job fails. In my answer, the mail is enqueued aswell so Laravel will dispatch another job. If the mail throws an error, the first job won't fail. This is usefull if you have to send multiple mails for a single user. If one fails, the rest of the code is executed anyway

Comment: What about Flame comment?

Comment: Well I'm looking at the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Mail/PendingMail.php#L121) and he's right. But my answer was just an example... I just wanted to give you a different perspective